# Generating a day event calendar based on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to get some eyes on some code that I wrote, and see if anyone can help improve what I did. Just looking for some constructive feedback to help make my code more performant, and more elegant.

From a high level my code needs to accomplish the following:

> Create a function that takes an array of objects that each represent an event. Each object in the array has a start and end time represented in minutes. The start and end times are represented as minutes after 9am. For example {start:30, end: 60} represents an event that starts at 9:30am and ends at 10am. The function takes the objects, and plots them as events on a vertical timeline. Events that have crossover will split the container in half, while events that don’t crossover will take the whole container width.

Here is the JS that I wrote to accomplish the above task:

```
//sample data - array of objects that represent events
var myArray = [
{start: 30, end: 130},
{start: 140, end: 147},
{start: 145, end: 155},
{start: 150, end: 175},
{start: 200, end: 250},
];

var myFunc = function(a) {
  //sort the input array from earliest start time to latest. Items with identical start times will compare end times - the longer duration item resolves with lower index. Assumes no exact duplicate items.
  var sortedDates = a.sort(function(a,b) {
    var caseOne= (a.end>b.end) ? -1 : 1,
        caseTwo= a.start - b.start;

    return (a.start===b.start) ? caseOne : caseTwo;
  });

  for(var i=0; i<sortedDates.length; i++) {
    var currentItem = sortedDates[i],
        itemDuration = currentItem.end-currentItem.start,
        itemTop = currentItem.start,
        prevItem = sortedDates[i-1],
        nextItem = sortedDates[i+1],
        newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    //set a default direction to each item
    currentItem.direction = 'left';

    //determine which items overlap and set a property to indicate
    if(nextItem !== undefined && (currentItem.end - nextItem.start > 0)) {
      currentItem.overlap = true;
      nextItem.overlap = true;
    }

    //ensure items flow in UI by staggering overlapping items
    if(prevItem !== undefined && (prevItem.direction === 'left')) {
      currentItem.direction = 'right';
    }

    //set class names on new DOM element based on overlap
    if(currentItem.overlap === true) {
      if(currentItem.hasOwnProperty('direction')) {
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'split '+currentItem.direction);
      }
      else {
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'split');
      }
    }

    //set the size and position based on computed duration and start time
    newDiv.setAttribute('style', 'height:'+itemDuration+'px; top:'+itemTop+'px');

    //insert new element into DOM
    document.getElementById('stuff').appendChild(newDiv);
  }
};
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/gotoliqaqi/edit?css,js,output) is a rough working example.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are in the code:

```js
var myArray = [
    { start: 30, end: 130 },
    { start: 140, end: 147 },
    { start: 145, end: 155 },
    { start: 150, end: 175 },
    { start: 200, end: 250 }
];

var myFunc = function (dates) {

    // sort the input array from earliest start time to latest. Items with
    // identical start times will compare end times - the longer duration
    // item resolves with lower index. Assumes no exact duplicate items.
    var sortedDates = dates.sort(function (a, b) {
            // replaced the 
            // var caseOne = (a.end > b.end) ? -1 : 1,
            //     caseTwo = a.start - b.start;
            // return (a.start===b.start) ? caseOne : caseTwo
            // with a shorter short cut, considering the start value are the same,
            // it evaluates to falsy (0) and the other part is taken, if evaluated 
            // to truthy, the value of the first difference is taken.
            return a.start - b.start || b.end - a.end;
        }),
        factor = 2; // for some more space

    // i change the for (...) loop to the more handy Array.forEach loop
    sortedDates.forEach(function (item, i, o) {

        var itemDuration = factor * (item.end - item.start), // applied factor
            itemTop = factor * item.start,                   // applied factor
            prevItem = o[i - 1],
            nextItem = o[i + 1],
            newDiv = document.createElement('div');

        // set a default direction to each item
        item.direction = 'left';

        // determine which items overlap and set a property to indicate
        // changed the comparison nextItem !== undefined to simply nextItem
        // and the subtraction to a direct comparison
        if (nextItem && item.end > nextItem.start) {
            item.overlap = true;
            nextItem.overlap = true;
        }

        // ensure items flow in UI by staggering overlapping items
        // changed the comparison prevItem !== undefined to simply prevItem
        if (prevItem && prevItem.direction === 'left') {
            item.direction = 'right';
        }

        // set class names on new DOM element based on overlap
        // replaced item.overlap === true with item.overlap because if not set
        // then it evaluates to false and if set, but false the it stays false, 
        // otherwise if set and set to true, it evaluates true, then no furter
        // comparison is needed

        // the other change is the comparison of item.hasOwnProperty('direction')
        // here logical or is applied, because item.direction evaluates to false
        // if not set, with the || '' we get an empty string, but if set, then
        // only this result becomes the value
        item.overlap && newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'split ' + item.direction || '');

        //set the size and position based on computed duration and start time
        newDiv.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + itemDuration + 'px; top:' + itemTop + 'px');
        // to see some information
        newDiv.innerText = i + ': ' + item.start + ' - ' + item.end;

        //insert new element into DOM
        console.log(newDiv);
        document.getElementById('calendar').appendChild(newDiv);
    });

};

myFunc(myArray);
```

```css
#calendar {
    height: 720px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#calendar div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 5px;
    background: brown;
}
#calendar .split {
    width: 50%;
    background: pink;
}
.right {
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```